# Add more disk space to Ubuntu from my Windowns 7 major disk and shrink from other drivers

Tags: disk-usage

Good Evening Everyone

First I wanted to give Ubuntu LTS 12.04 a shot with starting with a 10 GB and left around 10 GB unused separated in all my windows disk drivers, after installing and using I realized how great things I was missing and I actually start really moving my work on it, in 2 days I am now Drawing and designing Using DraftSight (it was not easy to install it)
and making presentations LiberOffice, so main problem now Law space (164 MB left)
I deleted everything I don’t need but I need the Designing applications so ;

As I know, first I must bring my Live installer CD which is in my case a bootable USB
and I have to Shrink the space I need in windows environment and make it an other new partition, by booting from USB and going to the live version,

1 - Starting G-Partition or the actual Ubuntu installation ?

2 - How can I merge the New Partition with the old ROOT ?

3 - Is there is any useful way, better then my way ?

3 - What else I must do ?

Abdulkader Baradi

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of (type in terminal): `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: 1) It might be more helpful if you can give a list of your partitions, e.g. as seen in GParted or output of command fdisk -l in terminal - no need for "sudo". 2) It's much safer if you reduce the size of your Windows 7 partition only using Windows 7 Disk Management Tool to create some free space to add to Ubuntu partition using live USB.

Comment: @Sadi, did you actually try `fdisk -l` without sudo? On a recent Ubuntu it shows nothing.

Comment: Yes, I did try and (because it's just a read-only action I guess) I get the same output under Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit, although no harm in entering sudo before it as long as the user is careful.

Comment: Excuse me but can you guys tell me how to write a Code or this Gray part in the text to write what I have in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jeroen and @Sadi i went back to windows made a new partition and connected with Ubuntu, but the issue that this new partition in windows ate the Linux Boot partition so i did it all over again but now i am free in space